# Display Links in TreeView based on Condition in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need some help on TreeView data display.
I have Web.sitemap where I have some url information with Roles.
and this is the data source for my TreeView.
Now, I want to display the data in TreeView based on the Roles.
Ex: If roles is 'A' then I don't want to display the link.

Is this possible?
Please let me know if anyone any some inputs.

-Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the Link based on a role you can do like this

```
protected void treeView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (role == "A")
    {

        RemoveTreeViewLink(treeView.Nodes);
    }
}


private void RemoveTreeViewLink(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
    {
        node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
        if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            RemoveTreeViewLink(node.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
}
```